# how to shorten a code to generate a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a pandas dataframe `df1` with specific column name from a column `col` of another dataframe `df` and do a merge with another dataframe `df2`.

```
df
    Name   House
0   John   London
1   John   London
2   John   London
3   Tom    New York
4   Tom    New York

df2
     Col  Val
0    Tom    3
1    John   2
2    Alex   5
3    Sarah  2
```

This what I am doing

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.unique(df['Name'])
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
x.columns = ['col']
df1 = pd.merge(x, df2, on = 'Col')

df1
    Col  Val 
0   Tom    3
1   John   2
```

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can pass column names as a named argument when creating the dataframe. This is in the docs. That's one line down, but really, I think this is kinda superfluous.

Comment: df.drop_duplicates('col')

Comment: I think you want `df2[df2.Col.isin(df.Name.unique())]`

Answer (score -1):

Are you just looking for a better way to do what you're doing? This is what I generally do when I need to filter a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
names = set(df['Name'].values)
smaller_df = df2[df2['Col'].isin(names)]
```

Edited because I didn't understand OP's question.